# Inserting random from a given string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

My purpose is to write an insert statement that adds a random value from a given string, more specifically if the person is married, single or a widower. I needed to first populate my table with hundreds of random entries because I need to run Autotrace on it and check its optimization. In any event, I first created the table, then populated all the columns, except for the one concerning marital status. Then I wanted to write a different INSERT statement just for that because I thought it might be easier then putting it into the plSQL block I made to populate the table. Here is my code:

```
create table employees(
    id_employee integer not null,
    name varchar2(50) not null,
    surname varchar2(50) not null,
    marital_status varchar2(50),
    birthday date);

ALTER TABLE employees ADD CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_employee );

declare 
  id_employee integer:= 1;
begin
  while id_employee <= 20 loop
    insert into employees values (id_employee, dbms_random.string('l', 10), dbms_random.string('l', 10), null, TO_DATE(
              TRUNC(
                   DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2016-01-01','J')
                                    ,TO_CHAR(DATE '2020-12-31','J')
                                    )
                    ),'J'
               ));
    id_employee:= id_employee + 1;
  end loop;
end;
```

Now that I've managed this and it worked, I just need to create an INSERT statement to basically modify the **null** value that is on every entry's marital_status column. But as I stated earlier, I want to have a statement that will return either (married, single, widower). Can this be achieved? Or is it not possible to give a command to extract a random value from a given string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you don't need PL/SQL at all - everything can be done in a single `insert` statement (or `select`, if you prefer). Here's how:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE employees
  2  (
  3     id_employee      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  4     name             VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
  5     surname          VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
  6     marital_status   VARCHAR2 (50),
  7     birthday         DATE
  8  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE seqes;

Sequence created.
```

Insert sample rows:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO employees (id_employee,
  2                         name,
  3                         surname,
  4                         marital_status,
  5                         birthday)
  6         SELECT seqes.NEXTVAL id_employee,
  7                DBMS_RANDOM.string ('l', 10) name,
  8                DBMS_RANDOM.string ('l', 10) surname,
  9                --
 10                CASE
 11                   WHEN MOD (seqes.NEXTVAL, 3) = 0 THEN 'single'
 12                   WHEN MOD (seqes.NEXTVAL, 2) = 0 THEN 'married'
 13                   ELSE 'widower'
 14                END marital_status,
 15                --
 16                TO_DATE (
 17                   TRUNC (
 18                      DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (TO_CHAR (DATE '2016-01-01', 'J'),
 19                                         TO_CHAR (DATE '2020-12-31', 'J'))),
 20                   'J') birthda
 21           FROM DUAL
 22     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20;

20 rows created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM employees;

ID_EMPLOYEE NAME         SURNAME      MARITAL_STATUS  BIRTHDAY
----------- ------------ ------------ --------------- ----------
          1 cpewxypfop   urkqkpapdk   widower         22.12.2018
          2 qjslhprqxf   jxoaennyqe   married         27.08.2017
          3 jjwknqkcel   zkmnwtoovv   single          25.10.2018
          4 levwydigey   numbxjvjtc   married         12.02.2019
          5 hswtiotjin   cjdfiastvi   widower         30.01.2019
          6 yxahvjfmre   dnlfmkphmv   single          11.08.2017
          7 nctcntredz   raqpofzufx   widower         29.05.2018
          8 wyivovpnoc   ikjakuzanf   married         19.09.2016
          9 rvtbqfgqnu   iuqjqosait   single          28.07.2018
         10 oislloosfy   xtfxpnceik   married         30.03.2020
         11 issbxtldsn   bovdghpjke   widower         21.09.2018
         12 gzgjdlvwcw   rmfqglwohc   single          11.12.2019
         13 utbznnyyhs   ojcswdwuvh   widower         21.12.2019
         14 etsvhavose   fypgntictn   married         23.03.2018
         15 myjijmagej   lvmpbcvcfc   single          12.09.2016
         16 givwwayxkf   hgemcfvnff   married         13.02.2016
         17 nquarbpzlf   zwgjukhgxg   widower         07.09.2018
         18 lnyyrkohac   ttygaxmvle   single          25.05.2020
         19 gmqboujcbb   qszmifozcs   widower         20.09.2019
         20 eegwdvqvld   dsembshumq   married         04.09.2020

20 rows selected.

SQL>
```